# Why does doctrine 2.2 use -namespace- and -use- without any include or require statement?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, namespaces, doctrine, php-5.3

I am studying namespace in php and **Doctrine 2.2** for a week.

I explorered several blogs and read several articles about namespace in php.

I understand that, when we want to use different namepaces in different php pages, we must write: `include('php page that belong namespace we want to use');`

But Doctrine 2.2 doesn't use any `include` or `require` or `require_once` statements for using namespace. Almost all script in **Doctrine 2.2** like that :

Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php

```
<?php
namespace Doctrine\ORM;

use Closure, Exception,
    Doctrine\Common\EventManager,
    Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager,
    Doctrine\DBAL\Connection,
    Doctrine\DBAL\LockMode,
    Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata,
    Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory,
    Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping,
    Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory,
    Doctrine\ORM\Query\FilterCollection;
class EntityManager implements ObjectManager
{
    /**
     * The used Configuration.
     *
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration
    .............
    ..................................
    ..................................
    ..................................
    ..................................
?>
```

There isn't any `include` or `require` statement in **Doctrine 2.2**.

But we run the page (Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php) appear fatal error,

> Fatal error: Interface 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager' not found
>       in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\DoctrineExplained\DoctrineORM\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php on line 45

Although **Doctrine 2.2** is stable version of **Doctrine ORM**, why doesn't use `include` or `require` for namespaces and `use`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most PHP 5.3 code out there is like that. Doctrine expects autoload to be set-up before you start using it. You can define your own __autoload() function, use spl_register_autoload() or use one of the implementations bundled with many of the frameworks out there.

This could be done for a long time too. It just took time before the conventions were adapted and namespaces pushed for that change.

Comment: i suppose that, you wanted to express the changing on namespace statements and conventions. isn't it? please tell me more.

Comment: What would you like to know? Having to require classes has always been tedious. It lead to massive includes that required too much code to be loaded and increased the memory footprint. Autoloading was introduced to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks again your reply. I just wonder that why Doctrine ORM don't use include or require in every page. And now you explained the reason. I thougt that before, ( USE ) statement works like include or require also. It is possible for next?

Comment: use is not the same as an include. It's related to namespaces and indicates in which namespace the classes should be taken. The actual instanciation of the classes will lead the definitions to be loaded. You should read the documentation on namespaces.